# Ubuntu apt-get install linux-image

Tags: apt, kernel, 9.10

I'd like someone to enlighten me as to what exactly goes on with `aptitude` when I want a kernel.

As we all know, there's pretty much the following kernel option:

1. `linux-image-generic`
2. `linux-image-server`
3. `linux-image-virtual`

This morning I did an install and it had `linux-image-generic` on it, so I ran the following:

```
apt-get -y remove linux-image-*
```

This removed all my kernels as expected, I followed suit with running:

```
apt-get install linux-image-virtual
```

Says I've installed `linux-image-server`!?

Am I missing something here, because I checked twice and it did it twice, however if I manually select a kernel (in my instance I used: `linux-image-2.6.35-30-virtual`) it will install `linux-image-virtual`.

This seems rather strange to me?

Details:
Running Ubuntu 9.10

Am I missing something? :)

Comment: I _always_ use `apt-get -u install ...` or `apt-get -u dist-upgrade` when installing or upgrading, just to see the explicit package selections being made.

Comment: @sarnold Yep, I'd normally do that too but I still find this a little weird, don't you?

It just seems to me like, logically if you ask for linux-image-virtual you should be presented with a stable linux-image-virtual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, here's whats going on:

The package `linux-image-virtual` is for virtual machines. Virtual Machines are *traditionally* servers.

However, if you installed the `linux-image-2.6.35-30` package, it should install the normal Kernel.

Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: See that's what I thought, I was just under the assumption that ubuntu would be very strict with their naming conventions, because isn't it correct to say -server does not have virtualized stuff in it (ie: xenblk) and -virtual does?

Maybe it's me who is a bit too strict? :P